# PayPal - obtain auth token lifetime / expire time in java (Rest API)

Tags: java, authentication, paypal, token

I've problem with obtaining lifetime of access token in PayPal (in Java language). At Paypal developer site is decribed solution how to get token, but not how to get lifetime (but they wrote that response should contains expired_in field...). 
There is also object Tokeinfo, which should have informations about token lifetime, but it is not clear how to get this object using basic credentials (like token/secret/id etc.).

Is there a smart solution to obtain token lifetime in Java?

If you need any code (for example how I get access token) please write it in comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not beauty solution, but solution (PayPal basic path is "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com" or "https://api.paypal.com":

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;


try{
                URL url = new URL(basicPayPalPath+"/v1/oauth2/token");
                HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                uc.setRequestMethod("POST");
                uc.setDoOutput(true);
                String userpass = clientID + ":" + clientSecret;
                String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());

                uc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
                uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (uc.getOutputStream ());
                wr.writeBytes ("grant_type=client_credentials");
                wr.flush ();
                wr.close ();

                InputStream is = uc.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                String line;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
                while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                    response.append('\r');
                }
                rd.close();
                JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                System.out.println(response.toString());
                JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(response.toString());
                Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> map = jsonObject.entrySet();
                for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map){
                    System.out.println(entry.toString());
                }
            }catch (IOException | ParseException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: i tried with same code but it gives error can you help>